# Trigonometric idnetity

Tags: trigonometry

IF $\sin \alpha = 3 \sin (\alpha+2\beta)$, then the value of $\tan (\alpha+\beta)+2 \tan \beta=$?

ATTEMPT:
$\sin \alpha = 3 (\sin (\alpha+\beta) \cos \beta + \cos (\alpha+\beta) \sin \beta)$

Dividing by $\cos\beta \cos(\alpha+\beta)$
$$
\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \beta \cos(\alpha+\beta)}=3[\tan(\alpha+\beta)+\tan\beta]                  
$$
Putting  $\tan(\alpha+\beta)+2\tan \beta= X$
$$
\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta \cos(\alpha+\beta)}=3[X-\tan\beta]                  
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$SinA=3\left(SinA\,Cos2B+CosA\,Sin2B\right)$$ Divide throughout by $CosA$ we get

$$TanA=3\left(TanA\,Cos2B+Sin2B\right)$$ Use $Cos2B$ and $Sin2B$ in terms of $Tan$ and then Simplify

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin(\alpha+2\beta)}{\sin\alpha}=\frac13$$

Applying [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo),  $$\frac{\sin(\alpha+2\beta)-\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+2\beta)+\sin\alpha}=\frac{1-3}{1+3}$$

Applying [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\frac{2\sin\beta\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2\cos\beta\sin(\alpha+\beta)}=-2$$

Can you take it home from here?